# How do you use multiple arguments in Custom Validation Directives in Angular 5?

Tags: angular

For example, the Angular documentation [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation) uses the following directive for the forbiddenName validation:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appForbiddenName]',
  providers: [{provide: NG_VALIDATORS, useExisting: ForbiddenValidatorDirective, multi: true}]
})
export class ForbiddenValidatorDirective implements Validator {
  @Input('appForbiddenName') forbiddenName: string;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    return this.forbiddenName ? forbiddenNameValidator(new RegExp(this.forbiddenName, 'i'))(control)
                              : null;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to use a @Input of say `Object` or `string[]` instead of only allowing strings? If not, how do you pass in multiple arguments?

The Angular docs uses it in the example as such:

```
<input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
       required minlength="4" appForbiddenName="bob"
       [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Multiple strings with a separator**

You can pass multiple strings with a separator.

For example, I defined a range validator as follows:

```
                    <input class="form-control" 
                            id="inputStarRating" 
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Rating"
                            mhRange="1,5"
                            [(ngModel)] = "movie.starRating"
                            name="starRating"
                            #starRatingVar = "ngModel" />
```

The directive then had code as follows:

```
  constructor(@Attribute('mhRange') range: string) {
    const arr = range.split(',');
    let min = 1;
    let max = 10;
    if (arr[0]) { min = parseInt(arr[0], 10); }
    if (arr[1]) { max = parseInt(arr[1], 10); }
    this.validator = NumberValidators.range(min, max);
  }
```

Notice that this uses a split to pull apart the two different values.

**Arrays**

You can also pass arrays like this:

```
  @Input('appForbiddenName') forbiddenName: string[];

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    console.log(this.forbiddenName);
    return this.forbiddenName ? forbiddenNameValidator(new RegExp(this.forbiddenName[0], 'i'))(control)
                              : null;
  }
```

NOTE: To minimize changes in the above code, I just checked the first element. But you could change it to loop through the array.

The HTML then looks like this:

```
    <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
           required minlength="4" [appForbiddenName]="powers"
           [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >
```

Notice how it uses binding to bind to the array of values.

**Objects**

You can define objects like this:

```
  @Input('appForbiddenName') forbiddenName: Hero;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    console.log(this.forbiddenName);
    return this.forbiddenName ? forbiddenNameValidator(new RegExp(this.forbiddenName.alterEgo, 'i'))(control)
                              : null;
  }
```

Assuming there is a type `Hero` defined. For the sample app from the documentation, I had to use `any` because no `Hero` type was defined.

The HTML then looks like this:

```
    <input id="name" name="name" class="form-control"
           required minlength="4" [appForbiddenName]="hero"
           [(ngModel)]="hero.name" #name="ngModel" >
```

> Bottom line, you cannot pass anything but a string to the attribute,
>   but that string can be a binding.

So doing something like this:

```
appForbiddenName='{"name":"Dr.", "alterEgo":"Dr. What", "power":"test"}'
```

Just provides it as a string. You'd have to write the code to parse it and turn it back into an object:

```
  @Input('appForbiddenName') forbiddenName: string;

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    const hero: Hero = JSON.parse(this.forbiddenName);
    console.log(hero.alterEgo);
    return this.forbiddenName ? forbiddenNameValidator(new RegExp(hero.alterEgo, 'i'))(control)
                              : null;
  }
```

Comment: DeborahK, I tried to pass in an Object to give my code more description. But I had a hard time escaping the characters in a regular Object. I'm guessing this with the separator and split is the best approach. Feels kinda bad. Do you know why only strings are accepted?